# Facebook card debugger scrapes wrong meta data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I tried validating my urls using Facebook card debugger but it seems it's scraping home page meta data instead of the page I'm giving it.

The only error I'm getting from the debugger is: *The following required properties are missing: fb:app_id*. But, I don't think it's responsible for this.

**To test:**

URL I'm trying to fetch: https://creativeafrica.online/work/malik--mina-by-malikdouar

Home page URL (working fine): https://creativeafrica.online/

All this is working fine with Twitter validator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the URL you are trying to test, you have the following meta tag:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="https://creativeafrica.online">
```

This is redirecting the facebook scraper to the homepage. Update this, and it should work fine.

```
<meta property="og:url" content="https://creativeafrica.online/work/malik--mina-by-malikdouar">
```